# Convert String to Int SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, derived-column

I have an `string` of original source and into destination table It was decimal(5,2), I try to change it with a rule

[image]

But when I run task It always fail, can someone help me what is wrong there?

**Update**

I also try `(DT_DECIMAL,2)TRIM(NAME1)` but It still fail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The task failure may be caused by some values that cannot be converted (contains non-numeric value)**

In the Data Conversion component you can set the error output to `Ignore failure` then if `NAME1` cannot converted to `DT_I8` the new column value will be `NULL`

[image]

You can read more in this useful blog article:

- http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/04/isnumeric-or-isnumber-expression-is.html

**Another WorkAround**

You can achieve this using a `script Component` instead of `Derived Column`

Just add a script component , add an output column of type `DT_I8` (assuming it's name is `OutColumn`) and mark `NAME1` column as Input.

Inside the script window write the following script (using Vb.Net):

```
Public Class ScriptMain  
    Inherits UserComponent  

    Public Overrides Sub InputBuffer0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As InputBuffer0)  


        Dim intValue as Int64

        If Not Row.NAME1_ISNULL AndAlso 
           Not String.iSnullOrEmpty(Row.NAME1.Trim) AndAlso 
           Int64.TryParse(Row.NAME1.Trim, intValue) Then

            Row.OutColumn = intValue

        Else

           Row.OutColumn_IsNull = True

        End If   

    End Sub  

End Class
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try applying a combination of DECIMAL and FLOAT.  I tried a test of this and it worked.

```
(DT_DECIMAL,2)(DT_R4)TRIM(NAME1)
```

This first converts to a float and then to a decimal.

Comment: But if you need to convert the string to an integer (as defined in the title of your question), then apply (DT_I4)TRIM(NAME1).  This also worked for me, but it did drop the decimals (string value of 8.11 became just 8).